# Some Bash questions for a newbie

Tags: bash, scripts, gedit

I am studying Bash, but there are some things that are not explained in my book. First I'll post a script, and then I will ask questions going through scripts.

**Bash Script:**

```
$ cat sortmerg
#!/bin/bash
usage ()
{
if [ $# -ne 2 ]; then
echo "Usage: $0 file1 file2" 2>&1
exit 1
fi
}

# Default temporary directory
: ${TEMPDIR:=/tmp}

# Check argument count
usage "$@"

# Set up temporary files for sorting
file1=$TEMPDIR/$$.file1
file2=$TEMPDIR/$$.file2

# Sort
sort $1 > $file1
sort $2 > $file2

# Open $file1 and $file2 for reading. Use file descriptors 3 and 4.
exec 3<$file1
exec 4<$file2

# Read the first line from each file to figure out how to start.
read Line1 <&3
status1=$?
read Line2 <&4
status2=$?

# Strategy: while there is still input left in both files:
# Output the line that should come first.
# Read a new line from the file that line came from.
while [ $status1 -eq 0 -a $status2 -eq 0 ]
do
if [[ "$Line2" > "$Line1" ]]; then
echo -e "1.\t$Line1"
read -u3 Line1
status1=$?
else
echo -e "2.\t$Line2"
read -u4 Line2
status2=$?
fi
done

# Now one of the files is at end-of-file.
# Read from each file until the end.
# First file1:
while [ $status1 -eq 0 ]
do
echo -e "1.\t$Line1"
read Line1 <&3
status1=$?
done
# Next file2:
while [[ $status2 -eq 0 ]]
do
echo -e "2.\t$Line2"
read Line2 <&4
status2=$?
done
# Close and remove both input files
exec 3<&- 4<&-
rm -f $file1 $file2
exit 0
```

**Questions:**

1. First of all, how do I indent codes in Gedit? I copied and pasted codes from a book, and it doesn't indent the codes automatically. Do you normally use Gedit or any other editor popular for scripting bash?
2. `: ${TEMPDIR:=/tmp}`
   Can you explain what this is? I have programming knowledge of C# and other programming languages. So can you tell me, assuming I'm not total newbie at programming, what the <kbd>**:**</kbd> key and the curly bracket keys do?
3. `if [[ "$Line2" > "$Line1" ]]; then`
   `[]` is same as test. But why does `[[]]` do any different?
4. `status1=$?`
   what is `$?` ?

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. I use vim for writing shell scripts.
2. `${TEMPDIR}` will expand to the value of the variable named TEMPDIR. `${TEMPDIR:=/tmp}` will do the same, but if it's empty (or unset), the value /tmp will be assigned to TEMPDIR, and also expanded.

   Having `${TEMPDIR:=/tmp}` alone on a line, will cause it to be changed to e.g. `/tmp` which will try to execute `/tmp` as a command (which will obviously fail, since you can't execute a directory). That's why the `:` (null) command is used. The null command ignores all input, all arguments, and does absolutely nothing. Run `help :` to see the description of that builtin command.

   See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/073 For the various things you can do with Parameter Expansion.
3. `[[ "$line2" > "$Line1" ]]`  returns true if line2 sorts after line1 (like strcmp in C).

   [("test" command) and [[ ("new test" command) are used to evaluate expressions. [[ works only in Bash, Zsh and the Korn shell, and is more powerful; [ and test are available in POSIX shells.

   See http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/031 for the dfference between the `[` command and the `[[` keyword.
4. `?` is a [special parameter](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Special-Parameters) that holds the exit status of the last command executed.  `$?` expands the value of that parameter.

On a side note, if that's an example from your book, I'd say that's a poor source for learning bash. I recommend reading http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashGuide which also teaches good practices.

Comment: hope you dont mind with edit, just trying to improve yours.

Comment: Thanks Rajagenuplula, I didn't expect this much of detailed information, this truely helps me to start on studying. I hope I can do the same later. lol

Answer (score 5):

Yes you have indent in Gedit. Open gedit and at Edit-> Preferences you can have the automatic indent option. [image]

About the second point , its saying like assume the TEMPDIR is at `/tmp` location.

Answer (score 1):

1. To indent code in Gedit press the <kbd>Tab</kbd> key, and <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>Tab</kbd> to unindent. All the information you need and the hotkeys list is at [Gnome Documentation section for gedit](https://help.gnome.org/users/gedit/stable/)
2. The `:` command is a built-in Bash command that does nothing except return 0 (true); but in this case serves to permit the evaluation of the parameter expansion `${VAR:=VALUE}` which assigns `VALUE` to `$VAR` only if it doesn't exist. If `$VAR` (in your case `$TEMPDIR`) already has a value it is not modified. It is equivalent to the construct:

   ```
   [[ -z "$TEMPDIR" ]] && TEMPDIR=/tmp
   ```

   i.e., "if `$TEMPDIR` is empty, evaluate command at the right (assign `/tmp` to `TEMPDIR`)".
3. The `[[` command is a built-in Bash command (as also `[` and `test`; they have executable equivalents too). The command `[[` has several pros and cons versus `[` or `test`.

   Pros: It is a built-in command, so is faster, and it has more functionality, like regular expression checking and parsing (remember: man bash is your friend) and doesn't need to escape some operands.

   Cons: It is not portable as it has different operators available in each of the shell interpreters where it exists.
4. The expression `$?` is, as the terminology in `man bash` states, a special parameter that resolves or "expands" to the exit status of the last command. If the last command was successful it should return true (0 for Bash), so `$?` will be a numeric zero; in other cases, `$?` will be the number returned by the command. For example this command line will show the error value returned by `ls` trying to find the file `a-nonexistent-file.txt`:

   ```
   ls a-nonexistent-file-txt ; echo $?
   ```

Bash as a programming language has a lot of quirks and peculiarities; studying the Bash manual is the route to success.

[Sorry for the apparent duplicate answer, but the others were unespecific and don't answered all the questions as they were asked (not meaning offense; I learned a couple of unrelated things there).]

Comment: Note that Bash has its own `[` builtin

Comment: @wjandrea You are totally right. I forgot mentioning it. Thanks.